# Storing data from multiple threads

Tags: python, django

Uploading files (images) via ajax multi-uploader (http://github.com/valums/file-uploader). Each uploaded file is saved in temp file. Put temp file name in dict with key of original name. Later every image will be resized in several sizes and saved to s3 storage. The problem is that there're at least 2 instances of the dict when uploading with excluding file names set, so I get partial dict at the end. How or where can I store the dict to update them from any thread. Tryed global with locking (read somewhere, that globals are accessible from all threads) - doesn't work.

Comment: Please enrich the question by providing what you've done, what's current problem, i.e. show us how do you process the dict. Or else the question would be closed soon I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **Redis**. It's thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

More info about how *uploading files via multi-uploader* works in terms of its architecture would be very helpful in your question.

However IMO one should always shy away from *global* data structures when doing web applications with Python/Django. Why?

Django `fcgi` and similar set ups are meant to run with multiple processes serving the end web server (usually Apache/Nginx), and I don't know of any way to safely and consistently share data between these processes; IMO the architecture doesn't suit this purpose, but is built to do work (fulfill requests) *in parallel*.